# No such file or directory FFMpeg Error on MAC

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am trying to build a ffmpeg binary using the following link

http://ffmpegmac.net/HowTo/

I was successful in creating the binary.
I could convert video files easily
This is the code i run in the terminal

```
ffmpeg -i Test.mp4 -b:v 64k -bufsize 64k test2.flv
```

This works fine totally
But when i run

```
./ffmpeg -re -i  test2.flv  -acodec libfaac -ar 44100 -ab 96k -c: v libx264  -level 41 -      profile baseline -bufsize 20000k -maxrate 25000k -g 250 -r 20 -s 480x270 -flags  -global_header -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 4 -segment_list test.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts stream%05d.ts
```

I get a "test2.flv : No such file or directory error" even though the test2.flv exists in the folder. Can you tell me where i might be going wrong.
I am doing the above operation to stream the video to my iPhone over air.

(Note- The command to build the ffmpeg binary i am using is as follows- 
    ./configure --prefix=${TARGET} --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads   --enable-version3 --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-filters  --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect && make -j 4 && make install
)

Thanks in advance for your help
Regards

Comment: There are two spaces between `-i` and `test2.flv`. Also there's a space in `-c: v`.

Comment: removed them. Still no luck

Comment: Please update your question with the command you're using and the full uncut command line output. Try to add `-loglevel debug` after `./ffmpeg`. Also, please include a directory listing.